# how to add name for touch event

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am try using touch event in javascript. I wnat to add mutiltouch event to a object, but i want give 1 touch event 1 name, because later i can remove that event easyer.

This is my code use click event:

```
 $(this).bind("click.soundcard", function(){
        //play a sound
    });
    $(this).bind("click.step", function(){
        // display the number step 
    });
    $(this).bind("click.selectcard", selectCard);
```

And when i want remove 1 event i just call:

```
$(this).unbind("click.nameEvent");
```

And my question is: **Have any way to do samething with touch event or have any plugin i can use to do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Event namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) can be used with any event type, so

```
$(this).bind("touch.touch", function(){
    //play a sound
});
$(this).bind("touch.step", function(){
    // display the number step 
});
$(this).bind("touch.selectcard", selectCard);
```

and then to unbind the first hanlder

```
$(this).unbind("touch.touch");
```